# Service Starting issue Windows 10

Tags: windows

I created a kernel driver and in order to load it I created a service, which was successful. When I tried starting the service, it returned with "StartService FAILED error 193".. How do I start the service?

Many Thanks. R.

Comment: Need more details really - what is the name of the service?  How did you create it?  Manually or with some helper?  How do you start it?  sc?  Anyway error 193 means "not a valid win32 application" and is often caused by not putting quotes around the path when it contains spaces.  See if this is relevant to your case : https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/812486/event-id-7000-and-1-is-not-a-valid-win32-application-error-message-whe

Comment: I used SC in CMD i just gave the service a random name and used the random name to start it, I will check your solution and see if it works, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @lx07 error 123 after going through the link you sent, (modifying the ImagePath in the Registry Editor)  error 123 is defined as "The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect." I don't see how it would be incorrect when all I did was add quotation marks to the ImagePath

Comment: http://www.fixerrs.com/2014/03/Steps-to-Fix-Error-193-0xc1.html